# How to avoid Serde needing the Default trait for a field that skips serialization?

Tags: rust, serde

I have this struct that is created by deserializing with Serde and I want to have a field of type `Url` in it which is not deserialized:

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Flow {
    #[serde(skip_deserializing)]
    pub source: Url,
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2c8d2f2301578e64c7252607a92ca5cd&version=stable)

Serde complains about `Url` not satisfying the `Default` trait. I have tried with and without deriving `Default`. Is my only option for me to implement the `Default` trait for `Url` myself?

Comment: If `source` is not deserialized, what should Serde put in it when deserializing a `Flow`?

Comment: Yes, I understand the need. I'm just wondering the best way to comply: ask Url to implement Default (an enhancement request), or is there some way to derive it? or do I have to implement default for Url, or other solution.

Comment: You'd have to implement `Default` for `Flow`, not `Url`, as [you can't implement traits that aren't local to your crate for types that aren't local to your crate](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0117). For `Url` to implement `Default`, the `url` crate would need to be changed.

Comment: You can use an `Option<Url>` instead.

Comment: I had thought about Option as a workaround, just that the field (later on) is not optional - but that's a possibility. thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`#[serde(default = "path")]`](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#serdedefault--path) on the field to give a function with the signature `fn() -> Url` that should be called if the field is missing.

Comment: Sounds interesting - let me see if I can use that!

Comment: There are multiple ways to solve my problem I guess, but this is the one that leads to least extra code, delegates the most (possible) to serde, and is most obvious what the extra stuff is for - so selecting as the answer. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible to [implement `Deserialize`](https://serde.rs/impl-deserialize.html) yourself and handle missing values appropriately.

Comment: Sure, I'd like to avoid having to do that and leverage Serde for deserialization. Thanks for mentioning though.

Comment: Sure this is the most inconvenient option, but also the most flexible one (and one that's often overseen, so I just wanted to mention it for the sake of completeness)

Comment: Hmm... it looks like I might need to go this route, as I am deserializing some files that have relative urls in them, so I need to set the base for Url::parse() to deserialize them into an absolute url....